# NoMethodError using Memcached Sinatra-style

Tags: ruby, memcached, sinatra, heroku

I've just installed Memcached on my Mac and updated my Sinatra app configuration as described in Heroku's [documentation](http://docs.heroku.com/memcache#using-from-sinatra), but I'm getting a `NoMethodError` when trying to use the hash-based syntax they specify:

```
>> CACHE['color'] = 'blue'
>> CACHE['color']
```

Using explicit `get` and `set` methods as below seems to work fine.

```
>> CACHE.set('color', 'blue')
>> CACHE.get('color')
```

If necessary I can use the latter syntax, but the former seems more elegant. I haven't tested this on Heroku's environment since I'd like whatever implementation I use to work on my local environment as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
class << CACHE
  alias [] get
  alias []= set
end
```

Comment: I would have expected this to have been defined already in the Memcached class, but generally speaking a useful tip. Thanks!